# She is a girl vs it is a girl

Tags: grammaticality, terminology

There is a photo of a baby girl with her brother but the baby can't be much Of differentiated as a girl or boy.
What would it be right to say?
It is a girl. Or
She is a girl.

Comment: Theoretically both. A proud father announcing the birth would often say "It is a girl!". If someone looked at the photo and mistook her as a boy, he might correct this person saying "She is a girl." (emphasising the "she").

Answer (score 3):

You can use **it** if you don't know the baby's gender, but using ***it*** when referring to someone's child is not very polite. If you know the baby's name/gender, it is recommended to use *he/she*, or even *they* (to avoid being impolite).

Comment: "It's a girl" is close to be an idiom, I would not be offended

Comment: @mplungjan It's a bit iffy. Someone I don't know well might look at me a little funny if I said that

Comment: These companies disagree :) http://goo.gl/XdDCGn

Comment: More to the point, the *it*  does not refer to the baby, it's a dummy pronoun. As skymninge pointed out, you'd only really use "she is a girl" for emphasis, when correcting someone for example. Other than that, it just makes no sense to use it because "she" already implies "girl". What else would she be? A boy? A crocodile?

Comment: @RegDwigнt, mplungjan I would say "It's a [girl/boy]!" is a set phrase only used at birth. You wouldn't say "It's a girl" when referring to a baby in a photo.

Comment: @Matt: I might. When you ask *"who's at the door?"* the answer isn't *"he's the postman"* (or *"she's the postman"*) but *"it's the postman"*. As RegDwight says, this is a dummy *"it".*

Comment: @PeterShor I agree that the *it* is a dummy it, that's not my point. The only way I can think that you'd get the response "it's a boy" when looking at a photo is if you're asking someone who doesn't know the child. That doesn't seem very likely to me, because if one doens't know the child, how would one know to say *boy*? If you know the child, you'd say "Oh that's Chester" or something.

Comment: @Matt: Given your further explanation, I think we more or less agree.

Comment: @mplungjan Haha, I didn't say that such a response would be reasonable!

Comment: I didn't say using **it** was incorrect, I said it's not very polite. I know some people who would be mad if I called their baby an **it**.

Answer (score 2):

As mplungjan noted in a comment thread, the phrase "It's a girl!" is very common on greeting cards, balloons and other celebratory items and would be considered the standard idiom for announcing the gender of a newborn child. But this is the only circumstance where "it" is remotely appropriate.

In the particular context you have provided, the appropriate phrase would be:

> She is a girl

However, that doesn't stop people from being rude and using alternatives. If you saw an androgynous person in a crowd, it is relatively common to exclaim:

> That's a girl?!

Answer (score 2):

I never saw a problem in referring to a child as "it" because you don't know its gender. Why are we even imposing gender roles on babies anyway? The PC crowd is usually the one who makes a big deal of not referring to children as "it", as if it's offensive....

Comment: How would you feel if I called your two-year-old child "it"? Much depends on the definition of the OP's " baby girl", is she an infant, or a toddler?